# How do I remove all occurrences of "," and "[" from the output in java?

Tags: java

Here is my code. The input consists of names of anime(japanese cartoons) which i have stored it in testfile in anime.txt and I am arranging them in alphabetical order and writing it back into another file name animeout.txt.

**The input file does not contain any comma or square bracket** but the output file has it.

```
public class Main {

    public static  ArrayList<String> read(String filePath) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

        int numRead = 0;

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            names.add(line + "\n");
            numRead++;
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n count " +numRead);
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(names);

        return  names;
    }

    public static void write(ArrayList<String> input) throws IOException
    {
```

File file = new File("Animeout.txt");
              file.createNewFile();

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

    writer.write(input);

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        ArrayList<String> names2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        String path= "anime.txt";
        String test;

        names2 = read(path);

        Collections.sort(names2, null);
       // System.out.println(names2);
        write(names2);
    }
}
```

Input file has about 200 lines. Below is just a small example

```
One piece
Naruto/naruto shippuden
Bleach
Fullmetal alchemist brotherhood
Fate/stay night
Fairy tale
Blue exorcist
Soul eater
Death note
```

Output file contains , and [

```
    count 105
    [11 eyes
, A certain magical index
, A certain magical index II
, Aldnoah.Zero
, Angel beats!
, Another
, Asu no yoichi
, Bay blade
, Beelzebub
, Ben-To
```

Comment: Are you certain that output is contained in the file, or is it only on the console. What you are posting is the default output of calling `toString` on an `ArrayList`, which is what you print on the console in your `read` method with the statement `System.out.println(names);`

Comment: @Robin I just checked the output file and it has comma and square bracket both at starting and ending. I have updated the output here.

Comment: Agree with Robin..It seems the toString method on the ArrayList is being used to generate the list

Answer (score 3):

```
String str = "[12,34,45]";
String out = str.replaceAll(",|\\[|\\]","");
```

output:

```
123445
```

Comment: I consider this as a direct way.

Comment: -1 I must say that appending a `\n` to each `String` in an `ArrayList`, then converting that list into an informal default representation, then replacing all unwanted characters from that representation and finally printing the resulting string is probably the least direct way of printing a list of strings, one per line.  Also, consider what will happen if one of your strings contains a `,` on purpose.  This is not a robust solution.  To be fair: The question is an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a `ObjectOuputStream`?  That is intended for when you want to serialise Java objects and restore them later.  I don't see why you need it here.

Just use a FileWriter, like so:

```
public static void write(ArrayList<String> input) throws IOException
{
   try
   {
      File file = new File("Animeout.txt");
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);

      for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
         fw.append(input.get(i) + "\n");
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      try {
         if (fw != null)
            fw.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         // ignore
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: With the close in a `finally` block, or using the try-with-resources approach if using JDK7 or higher

Comment: @BigBadaboom that was experimental. I have change back to filewriter now.

Comment: I was keeping it simple to match OP's original code.  And for that simple utility it didn't seem like it mattered anyway.  But good point - I updated the code.

Comment: your code is perfect. I don't even need t use replaceall function

Answer (score 1):

Your `write` method is unfortunate.  Try something like this instead (and remove the `+ "\n"` when reading the lines):

```
public static void write(ArrayList<String> lines) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("Animeout.txt");
    PrintStream ps = null;
    try {
        ps = new PrintStream(file);
        for (final String line : lines) {
            ps.println(line);
        }
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) { ps.close(); }
    }
}
```

The `ObjectOutputStream` you are using is not appropriate for simply writing lines of text.

Finally, if all you want to do is sorting the lines of a text file, at least on a POSIX system, you can just do it with

```
$ sort anime.txt > Animeout.txt
```

from the command line.